# App loses display

Tags: android

I am writing an app for the WiMM One Android smart phone.  After starting my app, the default watch face takes over the display and my app stops running.  Any way to prevent this?
Thanks.

Comment: This did it.  I used getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN | WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON);  Many Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried looking at the logcat debugger to see what's happening? It sounds like you're getting an exception and your app is closing.

Comment: If I run it from the debugger it works fine.  If I disconnect it from the debugger while it is running, and after the watch face has taken the over the screen, it continues to run fine.  If I then open my app's screen back up again, and then wait for the watch to take the screen again, my app stops.  I wonder if there is some intent my app should be handling that it is ignoring?